# Emacs: How to use shell command prompt with emacs?

Tags: shell, emacs

I am trying to use the shell command to facilitate commands like adding directories, etc. while in emacs. I am having problems getting it to work.

I enter `M-!` and then my minibuffer says `Shell command:` but none of my commands are accepted. For example, entering `pwd` or `ls` I get messages like `pwd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`. Any suggestions?

I used this reference, but it does not seem to help with my situation:

http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/shell.html

**Extra Info**
I am using Windows 7 OS. I also have cygwin64 installed, if that matters. Is emacs just connecting to an external shell, or is the shell built into emacs? If the shell is external, can I connect to cygwin64 (although it may not be worth the trouble).

Any suggestions on how to configure this properly? I found the following resource, but I am not sure whether this is the right direction: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsApp

Comment: What kind of OS do you use?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: You might consider using Emacs's built-in directory-editing mode (`dired`); you can just visit a directory file (`C-x C-f`, enter the directory's name, `RET`) and operate on it there; e.g. `+` to add a directory.

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NTEmacsWithCygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make sure that variable `exec-path` includes the directories where those commands (`ls` etc.) are located.

That error message does not appear to be an Emacs error message (from the Emacs Lisp or C source code), but rather it seems to come from the shell that tries to execute your command.